# Extract a value from a list if selected by TKINTER checkbuttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program that selects only the elements of a list that are checked in the checkbutton and then returns the selected elements in a new list.
I Know that it's probably better to create a class (and if this is your approach fell free to give it a try), but for now my code doesn't have any.
The main part of the code is functional, even shows the correct selection if I use the list in the main function, but the objective is to narrow down that list with the selection.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


#the main list with all players

lista_players = ["Cubanao", "martim","miner","Toninho","Bruno Pires", "Cacatuaba", "Dukalove", "Jhonathan", "Maximus",
                 "Rafael GX", "Sikilho", "Spatodea", "Taimica", "Tanaka", "zntta"]



#function that select players from the list based on the entries

def seletor_times():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list2.delete(0,END)
    time_1 = random.sample(selecionados, k=n1.get())
    lista_players_restantes =  [x for x in selecionados if x not in time_1]
    time_2 = random.sample(lista_players_restantes, k= n2.get())
    list1.insert(END,*time_1)
    list2.insert(END,*time_2)



#Creation of the tkinter gui

window = Tk()
window.wm_title("VWB Pro Team Selector")



l1 = Label(window, text="Escolha os jogadores :")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)



l2 = Label(window, text="Jogadores no time 1 :")
l2.grid(row=0, column=1)



n1=IntVar()
e1=Entry(window,textvariable=n1)
e1.grid(row=0,column=2)




l3 = Label(window, text="  ")
l3.grid(row=0, column=3)


l4 = Label(window, text="Jogadores no time 2 :")
l4.grid(row=0, column=4)


n2=IntVar()
e2=Entry(window,textvariable=n2)
e2.grid(row=0,column=5)



l5 = Label(window, text="Time 1:")
l5.grid(row=1, column=4)

list1=Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
list1.grid(row=1,column=3,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)


l6 = Label(window, text="Time 2:")
l6.grid(row=8, column=4)


list2=Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
list2.grid(row=9,column=3,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)



b1=Button(window,text="Gerar Times", width=24,command=seletor_times)
b1.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan = 2)

b2=Button(window,text="Sair", width=24,command=window.destroy)
b2.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan = 2)

##Creation of the checkboxes with a for loop

p=0
for player in lista_players:
    cb=Checkbutton(window,text=player, width=24, variable= p)
    cb.grid(row=p+1,column=0)
    p +=1    

# The Checkbuttons should populate this list:

selecionados=[]


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Some fundamental problems I see: you have to use one of Tkinter's Var types (IntVar, BooleanVar, etc.) for the `variable=` option of your Checkbuttons, not an ordinary Python variable; you must create a *different* Var for each Checkbutton if they are to be independently checkable; you must save those Vars in a list so that you can call `.get()` on each one later to get their state.

Comment: I tried to create this variables in the same for loop that creates the checkbuttons. But couldn't manage to link the new list with the old one. But I'll give it another try.

Comment: Try to delete `variable = p`, put one by one all the `Checkbuttons` in a list `buttons` and replace by `buttons[...].state()` for getting their states.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of D-00 and jasonharper I managed to workaround creating a checkbutton for every entry. Is not the best way but it worked.  After i put the variables and the buttons in two lists and used the Boll value of the variable to get the state and  them i got the string in the button name with this code:

```
#the function:

def ponderado():
    i=0
    selecionados=[]
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list2.delete(0,END)
    lista= [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17]
    lista2=[ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6,ch7,ch8,ch9,ch10,ch11,ch12,ch13,ch14,ch15,ch16,ch17]
    while i <  len(lista):
        if lista[i].get() == True:
            selecionados.append(lista2[i].cget("text"))
        i +=1

    d2= {}
    for i in selecionados:
        d2[i] = players[i]

    d2 = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
    time_1=[]
    x=0
    limite = sum(d2.values())/2
    for i in sorted(d2):
        a = random.choice(list(d2))
        if x >= limite or len(time_1) == 5:
            time_2 =  [x for x in selecionados if x not in time_1]
            if len(time_2) > 5 and len (time_1) < 5:
                time_1.append(time_2[-1])
                time_2.pop()

        elif a not in time_1:

            x += d2[a]
            time_1.append(a)


    list1.insert(END,*time_1)
    list2.insert(END,*time_2)


#The buttons (example)

c1 = BooleanVar()
ch1 = Checkbutton(window, text="Tomtom", variable=c1)
ch1.grid(row=1,column=0)

c2 = BooleanVar()
ch2 = Checkbutton(window, text="Tanakir", variable=c2)
ch2.grid(row=2,column=0)
```